# Why is Microsoft Edge autofilling disabled fields on my Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

We're struggling with a complex Webform that is auto-populating the wrong values into some text fields in Edge browser. The text fields are pulling data (phone number, email, address) from an existing Company Contact - and if those values are NULL in CiviCRM - Microsoft Edge happily populates these fields with previously seen but completely irrelevant and incorrect phone number, email and address.

We've since reproduced this on a number of sample forms.

Some illustrations - **this is Chrome** [Semper IT - with phone has a phone number in the CiviCRM database; Semper IT - no phone does not]. The yellow fields are the auto-fills from Chrome

[image]

And here's what **Microsoft Edge** does with this exact same form (apparently I live in Edmonton now). The blue fields are the auto-fills from Microsoft Edge. Thank you Laura for the screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Had the same issue with Google Chrome and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion
article seems to be working so far for me.

Comment: Hi - so the problem is that last year Microsoft made a decision to ignore the autocomplete=off for its browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in a post on the Miscrosoft developer forum:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9847360/

Some of the 'highlights':

**From Microsoft:**
“In IE11 and Edge, we made the decision to ignore autocomplete=off”

**From a developer:**
WHAT !!! ???
That’s why we are receiving so many UI complaints recently. This is a terrible decision Microsoft.
Please STOP breaking Edge by NOT supporting standard HTML correctly.
Edge should honor the autocomplete="off" tag.

**And from another one:**
“By Design” doesn’t mean that the functionality is correct. I’m struggling with a complex web form that is auto-populating the wrong values into some text fields in Edge browser"

Comment: Cool! Another reason to (still) not trust Microsoft ...